# Get Object array from jquery using symfony

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

i'm trying to get object array from jquery.
I have my function in deafault controller that return the query result using JsonResponse.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="result")
 */
public function getResult($id){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $results = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:ExampleTable")->findAll();
    return new JsonResponse($results);
}
```

In jquery when click on Search button I use the get function to call /{id} page.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-button").click(function(){
        var value = $("#text-set").val();
        var i;
        $.get("/"+value,function(data){
              //              
        });
    });
});
```

Now i don't know how to take this result from "data" and use it.
I don't want reload the page just want that jquery set text of div with result that get back from getResult function.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead of `$.get()`

Comment: But then how can i retrive the fields of the object returned by doctrine?

Comment: The link I've posted has it's purpose... ;) Read the documentation - including the examples. `data` will be an array of objects (guess from the called function `findAll()`). The exact structure depends on the server code. Just inspect the response of the server in the developer tools (network tab) or in an interception proxy such as [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Keep in mind also that your json results is probably not going to contain what you might think it does.  Use F12 in your browser to inspect the contacts.  Then read up a bit on how to serialize objects for json.